# Why does Visual Studio not hit breakpoint until second debug session?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

When debugging a unit test through either the TEST menu or the right-click context menu, VS2013 always ignores the breakpoint in the unit test after making a code change to the current c# test class.  Debugging a second time causes the breakpoint to be hit.

Comment: did you found a solution for this issue? facing the same here.

Answer (score 1):

My suspicion is that this has to do with VS2013's new feature "Keep Test Execution Engine Running".

You can toggle that feature in Visual Studio's menu via "TEST - Test Settings".

You might also be able to specify that behaviour by using a runsettings file with KeepExecutorAliveAfterLegacyRun set to false: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/jj635153.aspx.

Comment: I have this same problem (using Resharper 10). However, the "Keep Test Execution Engine Running" is grayed out for me, so I can't try this to see if it would solve my problem. (Maybe Resharper supersedes the built-in VS test Execution Engine?)

Comment: toggling Visual Studio's menu via "TEST - Test Settings" did not work for me.