# Visual Studio Premier 2013 Update 3: Only hits break points the first time

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2013, upgrade, breakpoints, visual-studio-debugging

I just upgraded to from Visual Studio 2013 Premier Update 1 to Visual Studio 2013 Premier Update 3.  Everything seemed fine until I tried to debug a REST service using WizTools REST Client (which is an awesome tool, btw).  The first time I hit the service endpoint, the break point hits and I can step through and debug just fine.  No problem.  But then, if I try again, the break point is never hit.  The service runs and the resulting JSON appears in the results window of the WizTool client, but, no break point, so I can't debug.

I've done this a million times with VS 2008, 2010, and 2013 update 1.  It's always stopped at the break points no matter how many times I hit the REST service endpoint.  The ONLY thing that's changed here is that I upgraded to Update 3.  No config changes, no solution changes, no nothing, except the upgrade to Upgrade 3.

I've searched here and in Google for a similar problem, and all I found was this:
[Why does Visual Studio not hit breakpoint until second debug session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22334206/why-does-visual-studio-not-hit-breakpoint-until-second-debug-session)

He seems to be having the opposite problem:  It doesn't hit the first time, but does every other.  And, he's debugging unit tests and I'm debugging REST service end points (don't know if that matters).

Any ideas?

Comment: I should have added... the only way I can hit the break point again is to close VS and re-start it.  Stopping debug mode and re-starting it doesn't do the trick.

Comment: I've never seen this.  Only thing I can think to check is whether the instance you are debugging hung and .Net magically spun up another to handle the 2nd request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution, for anyone who happens to come across this later.  For me, the answer was going to Debug > Attach To Process > select the process javaw.exe, which has the title of WizTools.org RestClient.  That's the tool I am using to test these REST services.  Never had to do this before, and it's possible there is a better solution - in fact I sure hope there is.